# Right click context menu freezes Skype/Slack

Tags: 20.04, skype, slack

I have 20.04 and when I right click for context menu in Skype or slack most of the time I get application frozen for a while, usually it passes after waiting some time but its annoying... Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Same issue for me.  Not yet found a workaround

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Slack via Snap, you could try installing it via another package manager.

I've seen people succeed with the Flatpak version, and on my machine I just used the default package manager to install Slack, which just works out of the box as opposed to the Snap version.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue on:

- AMD® Ryzen 5 5600g
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Skype 8.106.0.210 installed from snap (latest/stable)

My workaround is:

0. [Close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcT1w.png) the Skype
1. Open Ubuntu Software
2. [Choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA3cI.png) "Installed" tab and find the Skype
3. Click on "Permissions" button
4. [Toggle off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y9j5.png) "opengl: allows access to OpenGL stack"

Answer (score 0):

Run

`xhost -local:your_app_name`

> This disables app's access to OpenGL stack

For example:
`xhost -local: slack`

It still sometimes freezes on right click for about <1minute